# How do I find the path to the public folder?

Tags: plugin-development

Within my Craft plugin code, how do I find the path to Craft's `public/` folder? There doesn't seem to be a constant listed in [Craft Docs: PHP Constants](https://craftcms.com/docs/php-constants) like there is for all the other key folders.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of good discussion on how to do this and the pros/cons of each here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645082/get-absolute-path-of-current-script

In short, the most reliable way is to use PHP's [debug_backtrace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

```
$debugTrace = debug_backtrace();
$initialCalledFile = count($debugTrace) ? $debugTrace[count($debugTrace) - 1]['file'] : __FILE__;
$publicFolderPath = dirname($initialCalledFile);
```

Comment: One small amendment: that will give you the path to the `index.php` file within the public directory. To get the path to the public directory, you need to use `dirname($initial_called_file)`. Also, Brad appears to have been seduced by snake case.

Comment: @StephenLewis copy/paste is the only way I know how to program. Updated answer.